# prisma db seed & typescript problem with import and type:module

Tags: next.js, prisma

I learning prisma from this tutorial:
https://www.prisma.io/blog/fullstack-nextjs-graphql-prisma-oklidw1rhw

I have problem with step:
`npx prisma db seed --preview-feature`

I copy 1;1 code from this tutorial, and when I run:
`npx prisma db seed --preview-feature`

I get error:

```
prisma:warn Prisma "db seed" was in Preview and is now Generally Available.
You can now remove the --preview-feature flag.
prisma:warn The "ts-node" script in the package.json is not used anymore since version 3.0 and can now be removed.
Environment variables loaded from .env
Running seed command `ts-node prisma/seed.ts` ...
(node:34420) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/m/dev/prisma/awesome-links/part-1/prisma/seed.ts:38
import Prisma from '@prisma/client';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/m/dev/prisma/awesome-links/part-1/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1455:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/m/dev/prisma/awesome-links/part-1/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1458:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at phase4 (/Users/m/dev/prisma/awesome-links/part-1/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:567:12)

An error occured while running the seed command:
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node prisma/seed.ts
```

When I add'ed to package.json "type":"module", I get error:

```
m@ms-MacBook-Pro ~/d/p/a/part-1 (part-1) [1]> npx prisma db seed --preview-feature
prisma:warn Prisma "db seed" was in Preview and is now Generally Available.
You can now remove the --preview-feature flag.
prisma:warn The "ts-node" script in the package.json is not used anymore since version 3.0 and can now be removed.
Environment variables loaded from .env
Running seed command `ts-node prisma/seed.ts` ...
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/m/dev/prisma/awesome-links/part-1/prisma/seed.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:87:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:102:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:21:14)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:280:58)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:66:26)
    at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:297:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:261:34)
    at async Promise.all (index 0) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}

An error occured while running the seed command:
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node prisma/seed.ts
```

I reading similar problem on StackOverflow, github etc, but any case not working, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 19):

Another "painless" option using [`tsx`](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx), `npm i -D tsx`, then

```json
"prisma": {
    "seed": "tsx prisma/seed.ts"
},
```

[Detail](https://blog.liallen.me/run-ts-from-cli) if interested.

Comment: Compile options didn't work for me. This one did. Thanks!

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.

Answer (score 13):

Try and double-check your seed command in the prisma section of your package.json, it should look like the one in [the repo of the guide you've linked](https://github.com/m-abdelwahab/awesome-links/blob/main/package.json):

```
 "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
  },
```

From the error you've pasted you're missing the `--compiler-options` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem, while using t3 stack.

Install tsx

```
npm install tsx
```

In package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "db-seed": "NODE_ENV=development prisma db seed"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "tsx prisma/seed.ts"
  }
}
```

In prisma/seed.ts

```
import { prisma } from "../src/server/db";

async function main() {
  const id = "cl9ebqhxk00003b600tymydho";
  await prisma.example.upsert({
    where: {
      id,
    },
    create: {
      id,
    },
    update: {},
  });
}

main()
  .then(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  })
  .catch(async (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    await prisma.$disconnect();
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Then run

```
npm run db-seed
```

This was solved thanks to the [T3 prisma documentation](https://create.t3.gg/en/usage/prisma)