# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module when running `prisma db seed `

Tags: typescript, prisma, ts-node, mjs

I have a project that is using TypeScript, Prisma & NextJS.

I want to see my database with prisma using the `yarn prisma db seed` command.

However, I am facing issues.

The problem is the file that I am using to seed my database `prisma/seed.ts` is using an `import` statement and that file is subsequently importing a `.mjs` file.

So I get the following error in the console when I run `yarn prisma db seed`

```
import { env } from '../../env/server.mjs';
                     ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
```

Here is my package.json. In my package.json I set up a script to use different compiler options for commonjs modules. I also needed to set the `prisma.seed` property to define which file is the seed file.

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ts-node": "ts-node --compiler-options '{\"module\": \"CommonJS\"}'",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.5.0",
    "next": "13.0.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "prisma": "^4.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "yarn ts-node prisma/seed.ts"
  }
}
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file to configure TypeScript settings. I tried adding `ts-node.esm` set to `true` here but doesn't seem to work, so maybe some other config property needs amended/added.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "types/**/*.ts", "next-auth.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.js", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And here is my `prisma/seed.ts` file.

```
import { prisma } from '../src/server/db/client';

const main = async () => {
  console.log('seeding');
};

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

The import for `../src/server/db/client` is the file that includes the `.mjs` import. That is causing the error.

I need the script to handle both allowing import statements of TypeScript files but ALSO .mjs files. Not one or the other, I need both for the script to run successfully, I've found ways to remove the `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module` error but then get the following error instead

```
import { prisma } from '../src/server/db/client';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

For example;
Updating the `ts-node` script to be

```
"ts-node": "ts-node --compiler-options '{\"module\": \"ESNext\"}'",
```

and updating the `prisma.seed` to be

```
"prisma": {
  "seed": "ts-node prisma/seed.ts"
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hope the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807996/prisma-db-seed-typescript-problem-with-import-and-typemodule/76138529#76138529) I posted in another thread can help you.

Answer (score 0):

To run ES Modules, you can add the following property in the top-level of your `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "type": "module",
  // ...
}
```

Comment: When I add that I get the following error. 

`Must use import to load ES Module`